# MySQL - Show the restaurant name and items where price is over a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have two tables:

```
restaurant
| id       | name     |
| -------- | -------- |
|          |          |

food_item

| restaurant_id | name     | price |
| --------      | -------- | ----- |
|               |          |       |
|               |          |       |
```

I am trying to get the **restaurnat name**, **item name** and **price** where all the restaurants' items have a price higher than 10.

Examaple result:

| restaurant | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The King Fry | item 1 | 12.30 |
| THe King Fry | item 2 | 13.00 |
| The King Fry | item 3 | 10.60 |

All the items listed on their menu are > 10

So far I have:

```
SELECT restaurant.name, food_item.name, food_item.price
FROM restaurant 
JOIN food_item ON restaurant.id = food_item.restaurant_id;
WHERE food_item.price > 10;
```

I managed to join the tables and show all the restaurants and its items where the price is > 10. However, I do not know how to display only the restaurant where all menu items have a value higher than 10. If there is a restaurnat with item values both higher and lower that 10 - do not show. How can I get the result?

Comment: Hint: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_exists.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have two semicolons in your `SELECT` statement. The error is at the end of line 3.

As the other answer indicated, we need to knock out all restuarants that have a cheap (i.e. <= $10.00) food item. We can do that with an `NOT EXISTS`. When those restaurants have been knocked out, the remaining restaurants are those that contain the expensive food items. There is actually no need to put a `WHERE` constraint on the outer `SELECT`. The inner `SELECT` has ensured that the list has been curated.

```sql
SELECT restaurant.name, food_item.name, food_item.price
FROM restaurant 
JOIN food_item ON restaurant.id = food_item.restaurant_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM food_item cheap_food_item
WHERE restaurant.id = cheap_food_item.restaurant_id
AND cheap_food_item.price <= 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check with `NOT EXISTS` of a restaurant has food cheaper than 10 whatever

```
SELECT restaurant.name, food_item.name, food_item.price
FROM restaurant 
JOIN food_item ON restaurant.id = food_item.restaurant_id;
WHERE food_item.price > 10
AND NOt EXIST(SELECT 1 FROM food_item f1 WHERE price <= 10 AND f1.restaurant_id = food_item.restaurant_id)
```